# How to create a Doors Next Generation extension in JavaScript for advanced filter

Tags: javascript, widget, ibm-doors

Is it possible to extend the functionality of the filter in Doors Next with a JavaScript extension/widget?
The filter only allows AND/OR operations on different attributes. I would also like to have the possibility to save and load a filter from local PC.

Answer (score 0):

Right now it is not possible because extensions can be only deployed as widgets and are not able to modify filters. Next is that filters are not supporting OR operator.

If You want to have or operator in your queries I suggest using Report Builder (JRS) instead.